# error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)" IOS 9.3

Tags: ios, location, mapkit

I have already tried setting default location in product -> schemes -> allow current location is set.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location: CLLocation = locations.first!
    self.mapView.centerCoordinate = location.coordinate
    let reg = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate, 1500, 1500)
    self.mapView.setRegion(reg, animated: true)
    geoCode(location)


}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Did you set either of the Authorization request strings in your `info.plist` file? That's a common pitfall with CLLocation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24669985/cllocationmanager-authorization-issue-ios-8

Comment: yeah i fixed the issue  it was the info.plist.  problem