# Unable to find apple GPS's Privacy - Location Always Usage Description

Tags: ios, xcode, gps, privacy

I am currently working with Swift and I'm trying to get a GPS app working for a project I'm working on. I understand that in order to get the user's location, I need there permission through Privacy - Location Always Usage Description.

However, I don't know why but I cant find it, only Privacy - Location Usage Description. Can you help me or explain why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24669985/cllocationmanager-authorization-issue-ios-8

Comment: you must add NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription or NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription keys in your .plist file

Comment: How and where do i add it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Xcode 8 by following these steps:

1. Select your .proj file in project explorer
2. Select a target
3. Click on the "Info" tab to find your info.plist file
4. Use the "+" button to add a new key-value pair in this file
5. Type in "Privacy -" to get the different options available and choose the one that you need (location usage in your case).
6. Make sure you enter valid reason as a
   string value for this new key.

[image: Xcode 8 screenshot of Info Tab]

Hope this helps.